# Silverlight multi project template. How can I automatically link the Silverlight project with the web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, silverlight-4.0

I've managed to create a multi project template for our Silverlight solutions by using the VS2010 SDK and a TemplateWizard.  My question is how can I automatically link the Silverlight project with the web project?  I have two templates: One for the host web project and one for the SL project.  The trouble is that I cannot get hold of the Silverlight project GUID in order to set it in the SilverlightApplicationList tag contained within the web project file.  I have tried setting the Silverlight project GUID via a TemplateWizard but the GUID always gets regenerated when the the Silverlight project is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this be running the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll through .NET Reflector.  I figured the existing Silverlight templates must be using some mechanism to link the SL project to the web project.  I've added the following code to my RunFinished method on my IWizard implementation that is called by the root project template:

```
public void RunFinished()
{
    IVsHierarchy hierarchy;
    IVsHierarchy hierarchy2;

    Project webProject = this.GetProject(this._webProjectName);
    Project slProject = this.GetProject(this._slProjectName);

    EnvDTE.Properties properties = webProject.Properties;
    ProjectItem aspxTestPage = this.GetAspxTestPage(webProject);
    if (aspxTestPage != null)
    {
        properties.Item("WebApplication.StartPageUrl").Value = aspxTestPage.Name;
        properties.Item("WebApplication.DebugStartAction").Value = 1;
    }

    IServiceProvider sp = this._dte2 as IServiceProvider;
    IVsSolution service = null;
    using (ServiceProvider provider2 = new ServiceProvider(sp))
    {
        service = provider2.GetService(typeof(IVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
    }
    if (((service.GetProjectOfUniqueName(webProject.UniqueName, out hierarchy) == 0) && (hierarchy != null)) && (service.GetProjectOfUniqueName(slProject.UniqueName, out hierarchy2) == 0))
    {
        (hierarchy as IVsSilverlightProjectConsumer).LinkToSilverlightProject("ClientBin", true, false, hierarchy2 as IVsSilverlightProject);
    }
}
```

This code works a treat.